# Is "specialness" a mock euphemistic noun form of "mentally retarded"?

Tags: offensive-language

In https://gist.github.com/brixen/6705046, there's

> I recommend monkey patching Symbol#name in MRI. You can even do this
>   with refinements for extra **specialness**.

(As background, refinements is a feature that the author strongly disagrees with)

Is "specialness" a noun form of "special" ([Urban dictionary link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=special)), which is used by some as a mock euphemism for mentally retarded?

Comment: Yes, *specialness* is a (slightly quirky) noun form of *special. But ***no***, neither word *always* carries that particular euphemistic association. But presumably you knew that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usage of "specialness" is absolutely a mocking suggestion in the form of pure sarcasm. But no, I wouldn't call it a specific example of a euphemism for "mentally retarded". While it does mean roughly the same thing in the given context:

> I recommend monkey patching Symbol#name in MRI. You can even do this with refinements for extra specialness.
>
> I recommend monkey patching Symbol#name in MRI. You can even do this with refinements for extra retardation.

It is not really a true euphemism unless you refer directly to a person:

> Whoever uses refinements is certainly a bit special.

In its current form I would consider it more of a synonym.